# How to set attributes dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using angular material and ngx-form-schema in an angular 7 project. How can create a directive to handle all type of mat buttons? I want to send type of mat button such 'mat-flat-button' or 'mat-raised-button' to that directive then the directive show that mat button.

Answer (score 1):

Create two buttons. One with `mat-flat-button`, one with `mat-raised-button`. Then use `*ngIf` or `ngSwitch` to display only one at a time.

Comment: This may more than two button type needed. Is there generic method?

Comment: One way is to create a wrapper component which takes the type as an input, and in that component you use `ngSwitch`. A fancier solution would be to use `ng-container` and you can bind the type to the `ngComponentOutlet` attribute. If I'm correct, this way it also gets the component factories dynamically.